# Overriding progress bar in selenium

Tags: testing, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

In a function in my webapp, it sends a link to my mail and starts up a progress bar on my webapp, which validates once I go to my mail and click the link that it receives.

The problem is, I am supposed to access my mail WHEN the progress bar is loading, but I am not able to go to the next command once the process starts as selenium gets stuck there waiting for it to finish loading.

I have tried removing wait time but still nothing. Please help.

```
private StatusCode getValidationResponse(EndUserKey userKey) {
    int count = 0;
    while (RequestRegistry.getRequestValidationStatus(userKey).equals(StatusCode.IN_PROGRESS)) {
        count++;
        if (count > OUT_OF_BAND_VALIDATION.MAX_LOOP_COUNT) {
            RequestRegistry.setRequestStatus(userKey, StatusCode.FAILED);
            return StatusCode.FAILED;
        }
        LOGGER.debug("VALIDATION STATUS IN REQUEST REGISTRY: "
                + RequestRegistry.getRequestValidationStatus(userKey).toString());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(OUT_OF_BAND_VALIDATION.THREAD_SLEEP_DELAY_IN_MILLIS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
    return RequestRegistry.getRequestValidationStatus(userKey);
}
```

Comment: Please provide relevant source code, relevant HTML from the web-page that you are attempting to control, and possibly the URL itself if possible.

Comment: Its a project in progress so I cant share much, but I'll give you the piece of code that generates request and activates progress bar

Comment: I don't see a single Selenium code-line in here.

Comment: Its the source code of the page that I am supposed to check and not the selenium code. I was hoping you could look at it and suggest me some way to switch my focus from this to a new window.